# How to group text files based on content?

Tags: python

I have 2 text files with the following content:

Text file 1:-

```
Imports
KERNEL32.DLL
    0x40d1f0 LoadLibraryA
    0x40d1f4 GetProcAddress
    0x40d1f8 ExitProcess
ADVAPI32.dll
    0x40d200 RegOpenKeyA
Exports
```

Text file2:-

```
Imports
KERNEL32.DLL
    0x419128 LoadLibraryA
    0x41912c GetProcAddress
    0x419130 ExitProcess
advapi32.dll
    0x419138 RegCloseKey
oleaut32.dll
    0x419140 SysFreeString
Exports
```

I want a text file containing common outputs such that they are grouped based on the *.DLL names*. For e.g; This is my desired output file:

```
 KERNEL32.DLL
        0x40d1f0 LoadLibraryA
        0x40d1f4 GetProcAddress
        0x40d1f8 ExitProcess
 ADVAPI32.dll
        0x40d200 RegOpenKeyA
        0x419138 RegCloseKey
 oleaut32.dll
        0x419140 SysFreeString
```

I have written a script which will read the filename and keep appending the output to a textfile *final.txt*. What function of Python can I use to group the values based on the headings?

```
#start
import sys
value = sys.argv[1]
print value                 # Value is the filename
with open(value) as inputd: # Parse file
    for line in inputd:
        if line.strip() == 'Imports':  
            break
    for line in inputd: 
        if line.strip() == 'Exports':
            break
    if "none" not in line:
            print line.rstrip()  # print the line
            with open("final.txt", "a") as outputd:
                outputd.write(line) # write output to file
#end
```

My current output is as follows:

```
 KERNEL32.DLL
        0x40d1f0 LoadLibraryA
        0x40d1f4 GetProcAddress
        0x40d1f8 ExitProcess
 ADVAPI32.dll
        0x40d200 RegOpenKeyA
 KERNEL32.DLL
        0x419128 LoadLibraryA
        0x41912c GetProcAddress
        0x419130 ExitProcess
 advapi32.dll
        0x419138 RegCloseKey
 oleaut32.dll
        0x419140 SysFreeString
```

Comment: In your desired output how do you decide which memory address to keep ..?

Comment: @shaktimaan Good question. I am actually working with a large amount of files (100,000+) so for now the memory address does not matter. Only the function name matters.

Comment: you could collect all the data first in a dictionary (with the dll name as a key) and then write the collected data once all the files have been read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a perfect way to do it, but I implemented a workaround, This should do :)

```
import sys
value = sys.argv[1]
print value     

existing_dlls  = []
with open("final.txt", "r") as outputd:         #if this file does not exists initially make(an empty file) it else File not find Error will be thrown
    for line in outputd:
        if line.lower().find(".dll")> -1:
            existing_dlls.append(line.strip().lower())

dontwrite = False # Flag to keep track of address to be written

with open("final.txt", "a") as outputd:         #dont open this file for every write, rather keep it open for write operations
    with open(value) as inputd: # Parse file
        for line in inputd:                         #dont iterate again and again for similar checks, if statements are mutually exclusive
            if line.strip() == 'Imports':  
                continue           
            elif line.strip() == 'Exports':
                continue
            elif "none" not in line:
                if line.strip().lower().endswith(".dll"):
                    if line.strip().lower() in existing_dlls:
                        dontwrite = True
                    else : 
                        dontwrite = False
                if not dontwrite:            
                    outputd.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! :) My only concern is what if a particular .DLL which has already appeared once appears again with a different func.? 
e.g. for ADVAPI32.DLL - only 1 func. appears rather than 2. 
Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Thats why I earlier asked you how to decide which addresses to keep. Now I think you need to store address of each function for a dll.. For this make `existing_dlls` a `dict` object instead of `list` and store `dll` as key and list of `funtion names`. Writing data to file would get complicated. You'll need to read data from both the input file and `final.txt` maintain an overall dictionary and then write data again to `final.txt`.

Comment: Wow, sounds complex but it is an interesting idea. Thanks for your effort!